# Double integration limits: $\int_0^b\int_y^a \frac x{x^2+y^2}~dx~dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$$\int_0^b\int_y^a \frac x{x^2+y^2}~dx~dy$$

So the region is the region below the $y=x$ line.

So my integral comes to be:

$$\int_0^b\int_0^x \frac x{x^2+y^2}~dy~dx+\int_a^b\int_x^b \frac x{x^2+y^2}~dy~dx$$

I evaluated this but I got the wrong answer (Answer is $\frac14\pi ab$) . 
What is the integral supposed to be

Comment: Is your integrand $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Why wouldn't it be $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: Because it isn't formmated like that.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I don't see an $x^2$ for the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you avoid integrating in the given order?

If you do this, you get one logarithmic term $\log(y^2+y^2)=\log 2+2\log y,$ which you'd want to integrate with respect to $y,$ which is easily done.

The other logarithmic term $\log (a^2+y^2)$ you may do by parts, as follows $$\int \log (a^2+y^2)\mathrm dy=\log (a^2+y^2)\int\mathrm dy -\int \frac{2y^2}{a^2+y^2}\mathrm dy,$$ which is also easily done.

Comment: The exercise tells ne to use double integration so that's why I didn't do it like that

Comment: Wait how is the second expression inside integral . Shouldn't it be : $$\int \frac{2y^2}{a^2+y^2}$$.                We are Using Bernoulli theorem right

Comment: @Abhinav This is still double integration, only done in another order.

Comment: @Abhinav If you mean the last integral in my answer above, then I don't see how that essentially differs from what you've written. As stated in the answer, I have only integrated $\log(a^2+y^2)\mathrm dy$ by parts.